# Optimizing orderby sum in LINQ and Entity Framework

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I wrote a LINQ query that performs an `orderby` on an Entity Framework Core (.NET Core 2.0.7) database context using the `Sum` extension method. It works fine on a small sample database, but when running against a larger database ~100,000 entries, it becomes significantly slower and uses more CPU. I have pasted the relevant code below. Is there a way to perform the `Sum` faster? (it's essentially a weighted average on an arbitrary number of tuples).

```
var iqClientIds = (from stat in context.Set<EFClientStatistics>()
    join client in context.Clients
    on stat.ClientId equals client.ClientId
    group stat by stat.ClientId into s
    orderby s.Sum(cs => (cs.Performance * cs.TimePlayed)) / s.Sum(cs => cs.TimePlayed) descending
    select new
    {
          s.First().ClientId,
    })
    .Skip(start)
    .Take(count);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try using EF Core 2.1 ([2.1.0 Early Access Downloads](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/2.1.0-Early-Access-Downloads)) since < 2.1 do not translate GroupBy into SQL, causing it to be evaluated in memory in the .net core app

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @martin-ullrich. However, it looks like there's no complete MySQL provider for 2.1. Both MySQL.Data and Pomelo.EntityFramework.MySql fail to work properly.

Comment: Note if you have a lot of other fields not used in the `orderby` / `select` parts of the query, doing an early select on the query could improve the performance by reducing the amount of data pulled in by the `group`...`by` (e.g. `group new { stat.ClientId, stat.Performance, stat.TimePlayed } by`...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF Core 2 handles `GroupJoin` with translation to SQL and your query can be converted to use this:

```
var iqClientIds = (from client in context.Clients 
                   join stat in context.Set<EFClientStatistics>() on client.ClientId equals stat.ClientId into sj
                   orderby sj.Sum(s => (s.Performance * s.TimePlayed)) / sj.Sum(s => s.TimePlayed) descending
                   select sj.First().ClientId
                  )
                  .Skip(start)
                  .Take(count);
```

NOTE: I simplified the result (`select`) to not create an anonymous object for a single value.

Comment: Using a variation on what you suggested, I was able to improve performance. I'll just have to wait for a 2.1 compatible MySQL provider until I use group by again. Thanks!